# checkbox inside update panels refreshed and the

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When i take 55 checkboxes inside updatepanel then ..after selecting first checkbox the whole whole checkboxes will be refreshed and instead of showing images, it displays the checkboxes only in TFT monitors ... in wave form !!

hw to fix tis ..

or otherwise tell me how to insert checkbox checked value to textbox without autopostback

Comment: You want to know how to not postback when the client checks a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Set the AutoPostBack to False and not True!